# Multiselect swap box in angular 1.x

Tags: angularjs, multi-select, jquery-selectbox

I am trying to implement swap select box in angular like this:

Select Box:
[image: select box]

On submitting the form it should persist data in the backend and on get call the chosen box should be pre-filled with the items in chosen box which user selected at the time of submitting.

Comment: Please provide a js-fiddle or working code for replication.

Comment: @SumitRidhal I am searching for multiselect combo box implementation for angular js application  in which after form submission the selected value in the right box should be bind with a model:

Comment: I am using https://github.com/VoidCanvas/pair-select plugin for combo box ,This is my HTM and on form submission I am expecting the values of vm.user.IDMSCompanyMarketServed__c model in my controller , which I am getting as null.
https://jsfiddle.net/aquarian_gladiator/1s2vvg3x/1/